# How do I connect rest API with react.js app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to connect my react app to my api
This is thr API:

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get("/", function (req, res, next) {
  let dataArray = [
    {
      id: "Ford",
      name: "Mustang",
      Abrv: "FM",
    },
    {
      id: "Mercedes",
      name: "Benz",
      Abrv: "MB",
    },
  ];

  res.json({
    data: dataArray,
  });
});


module.exports = router;
```

This is the react app.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      users: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/users")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response); // Log the response object to the console
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((res) => {
        if (res && res.data) {
          console.log(res.data);
        }
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="App"></div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

When I start the server I get only the h1 on screen that says user data:

I get an error in the console that says Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<!DOCTYPE "... is not valid JSON`enter code here`

I don't know what to do to solve it

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Looks like there are some parts of this question that are missing. In your React app i see your hitting the `users` endpoint but in the API code you provided there is no `users` endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Assumming that you are running the react app compiled and from within the same server (not a dev server for the react app and another for node), then the problem would be that your node app is not exposing a /users endpoint. The node app shared above only exposes a root ("/") endpoint.

If you are runninng node and react as separate servers (even on the same development machine), then you will have CORS issues> This means you cannot request a resource running on a different host or port. If react app is running on port 500, you cannot request http://localhost:3000/users. For that, you need to configure a proxy to forward requests between them. The exact process to configure this proxy will vary depending on what tool did you use to generate the react application, but it usually involves adding a "proxy" object to the react app's package.json with the value of the API's URL.